Incorrectly applied remesh
I'm trying to apply remesh to this:

But I get this as result:

What am I doing wrong? Here is a video of how I do it.

have you applied the scale to the model? (Ctrl+A > Scale in Object mode)

So you're trying to apply a remesh on a mosquito net and it disappears?

That's not a mosquito net. It's a UI element that shows changes in mesh resolution for certain tools, such as when using sculpt brushes with Dyntopo and then pressing 'r'.

OP: I can't see any issue with the result, other than that it's a bit blocky, but this is common with the voxel remesher approach, unless you set the resolution insanely high. Even then, you may not like what you see. One nice thing about voxel remesh is that it's a fast and dirty Boolean Union alternative. It quickly combines mesh objects. Then you can get in there and start sculpting out all the kinks it leaves behind.

Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
